# Populating db data for django's built-in testing tools

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm using Django(1.8) + DRF + uwsgi + nginx and trying to unit-test API that I've made. To run tests I need to populate db (create users, for example) and use this data in all tests. So I've tried two ways:

Create directly in TestCase.setUp:

```
class ApiTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Account.objects.create_user(username='username', password='password')
```

Or use fixtures:

```
class ApiTests(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['dump.json']
```

Next I run my project through supervisor:

```
system("service supervisord startall")
```

After everything is ready I try to access my API in test to login, using:

```
login_data = {"username": "username", "password": "password"}
rslt = client.post(HOST_NAME + '/login/', data=login_data)
```

... but I can't authorize, because users somehow don't exist in the db!

As I've found in the docs to Django tests, TestCase doesn't write data into db, but store it in a transaction, that is rolled back after testing. And as I can see I can get this data only on test-side (using User.objects.all() that is showing that users are created), but not on my nginx-server-side (User.objects.all() on this side shows 0 items).

ATM I can see few options:

1. Somehow force TestCase to commit data into db.
2. Populate data in other methods (but which?).
3. Use different testing libs.

Could you please help?

Comment: Why do you want to access the test data outside the context of your test?

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by `test-side` and `nginx-server-side`?

Comment: @ShangWang, to run the tests during setUp() I do 2 things: populate db with data and run my rollout script for my web-server. So in fact I have 2 running python programs at the time: the one, that I've ran with "manage.py test myapp" (so called test-side) and my web-server that I want to test and started with "service supervisord startall" (so called nginx-server-side). My test-side will only send http requests to my server-side, so server-side will be separated from my tests' context.

Comment: Django has dedicated module for testing request/response behavior. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use web server to test django views even though in reality views do need to be driven by web servers. In order to test request/response behavior, you should use **django test client**. [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/) has excellent example about that, quoting:

> ```
> >>> from django.test import Client
> >>> c = Client()
> >>> response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
> >>> response.status_code
> 200
> >>> response = c.get('/customer/details/')
> >>> response.content
> b'<!DOCTYPE html...'
> ```

On top of that, the doc explains in details how to do `GET`, `POST` request and how to test view's response, etc. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Valid point. Even if a such tool as the "Django test client" don't cover my testing needs at 100%, I will use it in supposed way. Then I'll figure out how to test my whole stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You've already identified the problem.  Django `TestCase` executes in its own little insulated environment.  It will create test database prefixed with `test_` at the beginning of each suite run, and will execute each test in a transaction, so even if you start the the test suite, pause it after initialization, set the django config that supervisord points to to the test database, continue test execution you will still not see any data.

The reason you will not see any data in the example above is because the test has its own transaction, then when you make a request to your webserver, the webserver will open up a different transaction and will not be able to see the uncommitted data from your test.

To test your views (in my experiences) django TestCases and test clients, usually get you 95% there.  They are very fast because each test is executed in a transaction, they expose a test client, that mimics a request (url routing, middleware, view loading, template processing, etc).

Using `TestCase` should faithfully test all your logic and database interactions, but it still leaves a gap of if supervisor, nginx, uwsgi, django app are functioning correctly.  When you have extensive coverage using TestCase simple integration/smoke tests should suffice to verify the services above can communicate correctly.  Ie bring up the stack, hit a status page that will test -> Supervisor -> Nginx -> uwsgi -> django -> DB -> back out.

---

There are def a lot of options for purely functional tests, but why test at a flaky , timely to maintain level when django provides you the tools to verify your application in a reliable, quick, easy to use manner?

If you need a server to be available to a browser for a browser based test, django provides [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase)

If you need to write extensive functional tests I have found great success in exposing fixutre creation methods as API methods.  This way your tests would be executed AGAINST a stack, an arbitrary stack, in this case it will be against a test stack you bring up locally, but since the tests are separate they could be executed against a QA or staging or even prod stack.

Comment: Ok, I've understood most of your points. That's quite sad that Django's TestCases classes cover only ~80% of what and how I want to test my project, but I will follow your advice and try to test stackless first. Thanks.